# finding the number of 0's and 5's in an integer with a function

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm learning from a site that provided me a code that should find the number of digits in a string that are 0 or 5.

Here's the code.

```
def num_zero_and_five_digits(n):
    count = 0
    while n:
        digit = n % 10
        if digit == 0 or digit == 5:
            count = count + 1
        n = n / 10
    print(count)
```

I traced it back and it should work, but when i run it, 5 works, 50 works, but 505 returns only 1 instead of 3.

It should take the number, find out if the modulo of the number is 5 or 0 (hence the last digit is a 5 or 0 because for instance 505%10=5), and then raise count by 1 if it is. Then repeat the loop.

I've moved the count around, but i can't figure out what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Have you tried `n = n // 10`?

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for me. The basic logic is sound, but as the other comment says, you want integer division to avoid floating point precision issues, so `n = n // 10` is best.

Comment: "*in a string*" There are no strings involved.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you so much.

Comment: you're right gre_gor, good point.

Comment: also thanks cs95 for cleaning up my post. I was in the process of fixing it once i saw the jumble that was the code.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see, n is an integer, not a string.

Now, the issue is, when you divide 505 by 10, (n = n/10) you get 50.5 and 50.5%10 is 0.5, not 0 nor 5. Next iteration is the same issue, with 5.05%10 = 0.05.

You could try substracting the *digit* from *n*:

```
def num_zero_and_five_digits(n):
    count = 0
    while n:
        digit = n % 10
        if digit == 0 or digit == 5:
            count = count + 1
        n = n - digit
        n = n / 10
    print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use string instead of an integer because 505 divides by 10 is 50.5 (0 cannot be the first digit of an integer).

Try this code:

```
def num_zero_and_five(n):
    count = 0
    string_number = str(n)
    for char in string_number:
        if char == '0' or char == '5':
            count += 1
    print(count)
```